# spring insert a row into a mysql table using spring JDBCTemplate

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to create a new row into the "ride" table from a Spring application and I am receiving the following error

```
{
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 null

    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.put(RestTemplate.java:432)
    at com.pluralsight.controller.RestControllerTest.testCreateRide(RestControllerTest.java:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:292)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
}
```

I use a rest template to add the information into the mysql table like this:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    Ride ride = new Ride();
    ride.setName("Bobsled Trail");
    ride.setDuration(33);

    restTemplate.put("http://localhost:8080/ride_tracker/ride", ride);

    System.out.println("Ride: " + ride);
```

All the code from the project can be found at the below link:
https://github.com/roscasend/ride_tracker

Best Regards,
Aurelian

Comment: Check your in class 'RideRepositoryImpl.java' line no 43

Answer (score 0):

First of all, As a standard we should use POST to insert and PUT for update operations. This error occurs when an issue comes in server end. (HTTP 500 status  - Internal server error)

Its harder to say what happen by looking at client end.So please post the server error stacktrace.

Also one thing noticed give object array of parameters in you query
new Object[] { firstName, lastName }

```
jdbcTemplate.update("insert into ride (name, duration) values (?,?)", new Object[] { ride.getName(), ride.getDuration()});
```

Comment: How can I see the server error stacktrace? I updated the code as you said but the error persists. I will check again tomorrow with the post method.

Comment: You have updated the code -> build -> deploy i guess, where is this code deployed, look into that server log. If its tomcat catalin.log etc.

Comment: It is not any log file displayed in tomcat/log folder

Comment: When your server starts, do you see logs in catalina.out file?  Also do let me know whats the primary key of the table. In your checked in code i see that primary key part is commented out.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, your repository returns null object and server trying to convert null to @ResponseBody. Try to handle null in your code in below method in RideController.java. or use @ResponseBodyNull instead of @ResponseBody.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ride",  method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody Ride createRide(@RequestBody Ride ride) {
    return rideService.createRide(ride);
}
```